# Hedge a down-and-in BTC put?

Tags: options, hedging

What’s the best way to hedge a down-and-in BTC put?

I am not quite sure what the best practice here would be and would love to get some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but curious Where do you trade BTC Options?

Comment: Deribit, CME,OTC, some other crypto exchanges too

Comment: Btc or stable (usd) settle ?

Comment: Yup there are some DEXs that offer it. Any thoughts on my question above? Actually generally how would you hedge a put option?

Answer (score 0):

OK so down and in puts are very different from vanilla puts. The latter are fairly straight forward if settled in USD(T). If I were a MM and I had sold a bunch of puts, outside of directly closing my position out in the market, I may choose to delta hedge some of this, for eg using BTC/USD perps (or dated futures), if i wanted to hedge some of the vega I may choose to buy back the same strike or some other strike which I may prefer on a spread basis for the rest of my book.

Comment: If settled in btc, there are potential issues when the underlying falls very low, as the amount of btc you have to hedge the option with tends to infinity. This is why you will notice most new entrants are moving towards stable settlement